# Do Mathieu Groups fit in a chain w.r.t. subgroup relation?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

The question is simple one to pose after looking at the symbols to denote the Mathieu groups. Are these five Mathieu groups fit in a chain w.r.t. subgroup relation? (i.e. Is $M_{11}$ subgroup of $M_{12}$? Is $M_{12}$ subgroup of $M_{22}$? so on...)

---

(Edit with note on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group):) Consider simple as well as *non-simple* Mathieu groups $M_8$, $M_9$, $ ...$, $M_{12}$, $M_{20}$, $...$, $M_{24}$. Do they also fit in a chain w.r.t. subgroup relation?)

Comment: As Derek didn't explicitely state it: $M_{12}$ is a permutation group on a set with 12 elements and $M_{11}$ is a point stabilizer, in particular a subgroup of index 12. Similar for $8, 9, 10$ and $20, 21, 22, 23$ (the Mathieu groups $M_{12}$ and $M_{24}$ are 5-transitive, hence the numbers start at 8 rsp. 20.

Comment: OK I have edited my answer to complete the story, which has a consistent pattern. You could go down to $M_{19}$, which has order $48$. $M_7$ would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $M_8<M_9<M_{10}<M_{11}<M_{12}$ and $M_{19}<M_{20}<M_{21}<M_{22}<M_{23}<M_{24}$.

$M_8$ is not a subgroup of $M_{19}$.

$M_{8}$ is a subgroup of $M_{20}$, but $M_{9}$ is not.

$M_{9}$ is a subgroup of $M_{21}$, but $M_{10}$ is not.

$M_{10}$ is a subgroup of $M_{22}$, but $M_{11}$ is not.

$M_{11}$ is a subgroup of $M_{23}$, but $M_{24}$ is not.

$M_{12}$ is a subgroup of $M_{24}$.

The ATLAS of Finite Groups is a good source for information like this.